# Import CSV files into Excel/ Dir function is not working

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import

I'm used this great resource [Import CSV files into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899897/import-csv-files-into-excel), and it was working great last week, but this week i can't get it to work.

What changed?

```
Sub ImportAllCSV()
  Dim FName As Variant, R As Long
  R = 1
  FName = Dir("*.csv")
  Do While FName <> ""
    ImportCsvFile FName, ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 1)
    R = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    FName = Dir
  Loop
  Call KopieraUnikaRaderBlad
  Call RaderaLine
  Call SammanStall
  Call SidforNummer
End Sub

' Sub för att importera csv fil info till blad med namn från filnamnet
Sub ImportCsvFile(FileName As Variant, Position As Range)
Dim newString As String
Dim char As Variant
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & FileName _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "A00-40---1-D02------ Klar_allt"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ";"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ' det som är in kopierat några kolumner tas bort
    Columns("C:I").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select
    newString = Right(FileName, 25)
    'fixar till bladnamnet
    For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
        newString = Replace(newString, char, "")
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left(newString, Len(newString) - 3)
End Sub
```

Comment: The day  changed! What error / misbehavior do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error just Dir wont fill FName with anything.

Comment: have you activated macros in your workbook? What do you get if you add debug message `msgbox(FName)` above the `while` loop?

Comment: Yes the macros are activated in the workbook.
I get "" in the msgbox.

Comment: This "" means the files are not where they should be.

Comment: They are in the same folder as this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be Excel "default" location that changed, or you moved the csv files.

You macro `Sub ImportAllCSV()` will only work if you have files in the current directory.

To be sure, one solution is to use the complete path, e.g.

```
fName = "C:\local\my_existing_file.csv"
```

Otherwise, with your formula, `FName = Dir("*.csv")` calls to the directory Excel considers as "default". This is the directory you have when going to *File > Open...*

If you want to be sure of current path, then try [Re-Initializing "ThisWorkbook.Path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141506/re-initializing-thisworkbook-path), like with the below:

```
Set CurrWB = Workbooks("the_current_workbook_you_want.xlsm")
directory = currwb.path
FName = Dir(directory & "\*.csv")
```

Comment: I changed it a bit to

  directory = ThisWorkbook.Path

  FName = Dir(directory & "\" & "*.csv")

But when the code comes to .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
i get a fault "Can't find the text file to update this external datafield. Check so the file haven't been moved or change the name and try again."

Comment: @Mirkaminer  Then you should check the permission on your file: check that you have writing rights (and that no other process has it open - close all Excel instances and open only your "macro" workbook).

Comment: I have done that, didn't work.
But i open excel then the macro file from excel and not through explorer then it worked perfectly. So how do i change the code to work if i open it by double clicking it in explorer?

Comment: You may try to change current workbook: with `Set CurrWB..`. See my edit; if it suits your need, don't hesitate to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Then you can **ask another one** if you want to improve your macro a little more.

Comment: I used the function you recommended but that din't change the Fault
from the line <pre>.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False</code> i get a fault "Can't find the text file to update this external datafield. Check so the file haven't been moved or change the name and try again."
But if i open the file from excel i don't get any fault message.

Comment: Well, I guess your question is too unclear for me. If you found my answer helpful, kindly upvote it. I thinks you should ask a more concise question now, because you will lost people with all those comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer

```
Sub ImportAllCSV()
  Dim FName As Variant, R As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        R = 1
        Set CurrWB = Workbooks("Bok1.xlsm")
        directory = CurrWB.Path & "\"
        FName = Dir(directory & "*.csv")
            Do While FName <> ""
              ImportCsvFile FName, ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 1), directory
              R = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
              FName = Dir
            Loop

                Call KopieraUnikaRaderBlad
                Call RaderaLine
                Call SammanStall
                Call SidforNummer
                Call KollaFlyttaData
               'Call RäknaData
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub

Sub ImportCsvFile(FileName As Variant, Position As Range, directory As Variant)
Dim newString As String
Dim char As Variant
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & directory & FileName _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "A00-40---1-D02------ Klar_allt" 'vet inte vad den här linjen gör verkar som inget
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ";"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .WorkbookConnection.Delete
    End With
    ' det som är in kopierat några kolumner tas bort
    Columns("C:I").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select
    newString = Right(FileName, 25)
    'fixar till bladnamnet
    For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
        newString = Replace(newString, char, "")
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left(newString, Len(newString) - 3)
End Sub
```